How to prevent scientific notation when exporting a pandas dataframe to csv?
I read and modify excel files with pandas and export them as csv at the end.
One column can contain all kinds of text and sometimes a numeric string like "0123456789", note the leading zero. That leading zero seems to cause excel to autoformat those cells and display them in scientific format.
I do not want to change that cell value when exporting the csv at the end but it always puts it in the scientific format by default eventhough it wasn't in that format in the excel since its formatted as "text" or has an apostrophe at the beginning (which is not displayed in excel files).
If I put an apostrophe at the beginning manually in python it does not change the value to scientific format however the apostrophe is visible in the csv since there is no formatting in a csv and also I can have non-numeric values in that column as well and putting an apostrophe at the beginning wouldnt make sense in every case.
How can I read an excel and export it as csv without displaying those numeric strings in scientific format and just keeping them as they are without having to do anything manually in the csv afterwards?

From excel, you can format your csv. I believe by default excel attempts to infer the type.  From the csv writer I don't think there is a way as csv contains no typing.

According to the pandas documentation to_csv does not contain any column formating, however you can define the dtype when reading your original excel. If you share the code you are using to read the excel i could be able to help further. Thus you can go and check out the doucumentation on the dtype parameter. It is possible for you to format your column as a string from the begining, and keep the pandas algorithm from infering the format on that column. Let me know if it works https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

The code to read the excel looks like this:
original = pd.read_excel(filename, dtype={"A" : str})
However this does not work. When I open the CSV at the end, which is created like this:
df.to_csv(file_path, index=False, encoding="utf-8-sig", sep=";")
The column is in scientic format ..

Also opening the original excel file I get a message that the column is being formatted as Text, to preserve leading zeros. Depending on what I try I also get a message when opening the final CSV to "convert" those numbers in scientific format or not. I would like to just have them as text, NOT in scientific format in the first place. It doesnt seem to be possible..

Seems to me that the problem is excel itself when you are trying to open the files. Would you care to paste a copule of lines of the resulting csv file to see how pd.To_csv is working?
